# Finalizar compra y enviar carrito por whatsapp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, string

Estoy haciendo una tienda online con react y me gastaría que el botón de Finalizar Compra te redirija a Whatsapp con el listado de los productos pero no se como hacerlo...
sucede lo siguiente. carrito es un array de objetos si envió simplemente carrito Whatsapp me manda un mensaje diciendo [objeto, objeto]... asi que probé recorrer carrito con for
consola me da todos objetos sueltos ahora...
pero si envió element me envía solamente el ultimo producto...
como hago para que envié todos los productos

```
function finalizarCompra(){
        for (let i = 0; i < Carrito.length; i++) {
            let element = Carrito[i];
            console.log(element);
            window.location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=333333333&text=Me%20interesan%20los%20siguientes%20productos' + ' ' + element.Nombre
        }
    }
```

Comment: Para evitar que te llegue `[objeto, objeto]` puedes usar `JSON.stringify(Carrito)` y transformará tu objeto en una cadena de texto. De todas formas no sé en qué formato esperas enviar los elementos a wsp. Recuerda que wsp es una app de mensajería, y los mensajes son texto. Espero que no estes pensando que si envías un objeto Javastscript podrás verlo tal cual en wsp, recuerda, wsp no entiende de objetos Js, simplemente maneja texto (y audios, videos e imágenes). Quizas exista una API a la que te puedas integrar para hacer uso de las funcionalidades de wsp business

Comment: si en mensaje quiero que me devuelva la lista del carrito... lo probe a JSON.stringify... de momento es lo que mas sirve... pero me devuelve todos los productos y el producto entero y no quiero que me mande todos los detalles del producto solamente algunas propiedades.. junto con todas la llaves y corchetes propios de un array y objetos .. lo que pensaba es usar split y joy pero supongo que debe haber una forma mas fácil de hacerlo..

Comment: Lo que puedes usar es un arreglo auxiliar y un bucle para obtener solo las propiedades que necesites de los productos. Te lo colocaré como respuesta para que se entienda mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Primera Solución

Una posible solución sería usar un array auxiliar para obtener únicamente las propiedades de los productos que necesites, como por ejemplo solo el nombre y enviarlo a la API de Whatsapp convirtiendo previamente ese arreglo en una cadena.

Esto sería:

```js
const Carrito = [
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 1',
      Monto: 100.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 2',
      Monto: 150.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 3',
      Monto: 200.0
    }
];

function finalizarCompra(){
  let productosParaWsp = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < Carrito.length; i++) {
      productosParaWsp.push(Carrito[i].Nombre);
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(productosParaWsp));
   //window.location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=333333333&text=Me%20interesan%20los%20siguientes%20productos' + ' ' + JSON.stringify(productosParaWsp) // Comento esta línea para no redirigir realmente en este ejemplo
}

finalizarCompra();
```

Para el mismo fin podemos usar un [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para tener un código más reducido:

```js
const Carrito = [
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 1',
      Monto: 100.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 2',
      Monto: 150.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 3',
      Monto: 200.0
    }
];

function finalizarCompra(){
  let productosParaWsp = Carrito.map(producto => producto.Nombre);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(productosParaWsp));
   //window.location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=333333333&text=Me%20interesan%20los%20siguientes%20productos' + ' ' + JSON.stringify(productosParaWsp) // Comento esta línea para no redirigir realmente en este ejemplo
}

finalizarCompra();
```

Recuerda que puedes ejecutar los ejemplos para ver el resultado.

---

### Segunda Solución

Todo depende de cómo esté formado tu arreglo de productos al que llamas `Carrito`, pero la idea general es extraer el nombre y no todas las propiedades de los productos.

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es un formato que sea más amigable con los usuarios, podríamos generar una cadena de texto con un formato más ordenado, también le añadiremos el monto en este ejemplo

```js
const Carrito = [
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 1',
      Monto: 100.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 2',
      Monto: 150.0
    },
    {
      Nombre: 'producto 3',
      Monto: 200.0
    }
];

function finalizarCompra(){
  let productosParaWsp = Carrito.map(producto => `- ${producto.Nombre}, $${producto.Monto}`); // Le añadimos un guión delante del nombre y también el monto
  const productosConFormatoAmigable = productosParaWsp.join('\n'); // Unimos todos los elementos del array en una cadena usando como separador el salto de línea
  console.log(productosConFormatoAmigable); // Como la variable ya es una cadena, no necesitamos usar JSON.strignify()
   //window.location.href = 'https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=333333333&text=Me%20interesan%20los%20siguientes%20productos' + ' ' + productosConFormatoAmigable // Comento esta línea para no redirigir realmente en este ejemplo
}

finalizarCompra();
```

En este ejemplo, ademas de obtener el arreglo de nombres y montos de los productos, generamos una cadena de texto que ya tiene un formato más amigable. Puedes leer más sobre [array.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) y sobre [interpolación de cadenas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

> Por otro lado, quizás necesites codificar tu cadena para que viaje
> correctamente como query param. (Quizás no, depende de cómo funcione la redirección).
>
> Si llegas a necesitarlo, en vez de enviar únicamente
> `productosConFormatoAmigable` puedes envolverlo en
> `encodeURIComponent(productosConFormatoAmigable)`

Comment: genio todavía no las probé pero creo que me van a servir gracias mañana es lo primero que intento